# initializer element not computable at load time

Tags: c, element, initializer

After upgrading from gcc 4.4.x to gcc 4.7.0, I started seeing:

```
error: initializer element not computable at load time
```

for the following snippet:

```
int prm_arr[] = {prm.field1, prm.field2, prm.field3};
```

This code worked fine with the gcc 4.4.x. I tried using `-std=c99` option but it did not work. The following snippet might work

```
prm_arr[0] = prm.field1;
prm_arr[1] = prm.field2;
prm_arr[2] = prm.field3;
```

but, what is triggering this error?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular it matters whether this code is at file scope or block scope, and what `prm.field1` etc. are.

Answer (score 0):

In C89, initializer lists must be constant expressions known at compile-time. (however it works in C99 though). Hence what you are doing is not the correct way. The second snippet you posted is sure to work.

Comment: Initializers of non-static variables don't have to be constant expressions since C99, and OP says they tried `-std=c99`